# Создание виртуальной машины в kvm

Tags: opensuse, kvm, виртуализация

Как создать виртуальную машину в `kvm OpenSUSE 12.1 x86_64`. В `x86_32 OpenSUSE` всё создаётся нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, что загружен модуль ядра:

```
lsmod | grep kvm
```

Создание виртуальной машины:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow /vms/vmtest.img 10Gqemu-system-x86_64 -hda /vms/vmtest.img -cdrom /media.iso -boot d  -m 512
```

Answer (score 1):

1. kvm или libvirt? если libvirt, то можно через GUI - `virt-manager`, а можно и через cli - `virsh` / `virt-install`
2. kvm не поддерживается на 32-битных хостах, очень не советую даже начинать что то на этом строить
3. почему именно opensuse?